# How to hide the check box after the form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hello friends this i am facing some problem...I have multiple check boxes and by selecting each check box i am inserting the users details to database by Ajax. the records records are inserting to database but my problem is that , suppose i have 5 users in the page, suppose i am selecting the 3 user check boxes and submit , and if the insertion succeed then i want that the 3 selected users will not shown on page. i use Google many tips but can't solve the problem.

```
 //this is the menu.php


  <li class="invitetab"><a href="#Invite"><span>Invite</span></a></li>

     $('.invitetab').one('click', function(){
          var rp = '<?php echo $baseUrl ;?>/themes/gr-mist/pagemenu/parts/';

            var v = '<?php echo $_GET['pageid'];?>';
            var userid = '<?php echo $_SESSION['db_user_info']['id'] ?>';
                $( document ).ready(function() {

                $.ajax({
                url: ""+rp+"invite.php?pageid="+v+"&userid="+userid,
                type: 'POST',
                beforeSend: function()
                {
                $("#loading_img").show();
                },
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $("#loading_img").hide();
                    $("#Invite").append(data);

                }       
                });
                });
            });
```

---

```
   //And this is the invite.php

       $('.gr-post-btn-submit').click(function(){ // when a feature button is selected
    var rp = '<?php echo $config->baseUrl ;?>/themes/gr-mist/pagemenu/parts/';
    var v = '<?php echo $_GET['pageid'];?>';
   var userid = '<?php echo $user_id ?>';


   var serialize = $('.abc').serialize(); // takes all the values of the filter
   $.ajax({  
     type : 'POST',
    url: ""+rp+"sendinv.php?pageid="+v+"&userid="+userid, // sends the values to ajax file
     data : serialize,

        beforeSend: function()
                {
                $("#loading_own").show();
                $("#Invite").css({ opacity: 0.5 });

                },
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $("#loading_own").hide();
                    $("#Invite").css({ opacity: 5.6 });
                    // $("#Invite").show();
  //this is the portion where we have to do some thing to hide the inserting check boxes 

                  } 



            }); 
          });           





     <form method="post"  class="abc" id="" name="inviteform" 

     enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#"> 

                 <?php

              $sql = "select * from gr_user_friendships where toid=$user_id and status = 1";

            $pagd = $_GET['pageid'];
            $liked_users = $db->select($sql);
   $count = 0;
   for($i=0; $i<count($liked_users); $i++)
    {

   $extrct_fr = "select * from gr_page_likes where page_id=".$pagd." and      receiver_id=".$liked_users[$i]['fromid'];
  //echo $extrct_fr;
  $frnd = $db->select($extrct_fr);

  if(count($frnd)>0)
  {
  $invt = $db->select("select * from gr_user_friendships where toid=$user_id and fromid!=$frnd[0]['receiver_id']");
 $invt_id = $invt[0]['fromid'];

    }
   else
  {
  $invt_id = $liked_users[$i]['fromid'];    
      }

         if(!empty($invt_id))
           $count = 1;
             $user = "Select * from gr_users where id = $invt_id";
             //echo $user;

            $table =    mysql_query($user);
            $dbc =  mysql_fetch_array($table);
            $usid= $dbc['id'];
            $bab    = $dbc['name'];
            $imgs = $dbc['avatar'];
            $image_of_fr =                    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/users/".$usid."/profile/profile-pic/thumb/".$imgs;
            $image_location_f = $config->baseUrl."/uploads/users/".$usid."/profile/profile-pic/thumb/".$imgs;

            if(file_exists($image_of_fr))
            {
                $imgp = $image_location_f;

            }
            else
            {
                $imgp = $config->baseUrl."/themes/gr-mist/includes/images.jpg";
            }


    if(!empty($invt_id)){
            ?>
            <style type="text/css">

            #users_<?php echo $invt_id ?>
            {
                 width:147px;
                 height:54px;

                 display:inline-block;
            }

            </style>
   <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" id="gcc_<?php echo $invt_id ?>" name="pgliker[]"  value="<?php echo $invt_id ?>"/>
            <img width="30" height="30" src="<?php echo $imgp;?>"/>
            <?php echo $bab; ?>


           <?php 
           }  
        }//end of for


           ?>
            <br>
           <?php if($count){ ?>
           <span style="color:blue; font-weight:bold;"  >
           <input type="checkbox" id="selecctall"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Select All</span>

<input type="button"   name="gr_submits" class="gr-post-btn-submit" value="invite" id="submits"/>

<?php } ?>
</form>
```

---

and this is the sendinv.php

```
  global $db;
    $myliker = $_POST['pgliker'];
    $pageid = $_GET['pageid'];
    $userid = $_GET['userid'];




     foreach($myliker as $tps)
    {
        $sql = "Insert into gr_page_likes   values('',$pageid,$userid,$tps,0)";
        $db->insert($sql);
     }
```

Comment: in your ajax add this code: `$('form.abc input[type="checkbox"]).hide();`

Comment: should i put it after success

Comment: process it in click function, add error handler in your ajax and add dis code: `$('form.abc input[type="checkbox"]).show();`

Comment: After successful submission of form the records stays there..when i refresh then the records goes from the page...i use the informal way to refresh div after the button clicked but it didn't solve my problem...now i wan to show that checkbox which was not previouly ticked...what i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**In you invite.php put the element which you want to hide after success
 form submission into one div*//

//replace your one with  this one.
       <div id="gcc_<?php echo $invt_id ?>">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1"  name="pgliker[]"  value="<?php echo $invt_id ?>"/>
            <img width="30" height="30" src="<?php echo $imgp;?>"/>
            <?php echo $bab; ?>
            </div>


 /**Now make an array in your sendinv.php and encode it with json incode***/

 //replace your sendinv.php with this one.


    $arr = array();

    foreach($myliker as $tps)
    {
   $sql = "Insert into gr_page_likes values('',$pageid,$userid,$tps,0)";
    $db->insert($sql);
    $arr[] = $tps;
    }
    echo json_encode($arr);
    exit;

 /**After  in your invite.php in the success block run
  jquery foreach with the data and hide the checked  boxes with the ids associted after submission. */

   $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
             // alert( key + ": " + value );
    $("#gcc_"+value).hide();//the div for each checked user

               });
```